# PowerApps Yes/No checkbox submitted to a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

What is the best approach to save Yes/No checkbox value into a SharePoint List. I have a Custom List call "HelpDesk", added a column type "Single line of text" - Call "Is this a new Issue"

Have a checkbox [ ]Yes and checkbox [ ]No

I been reading about `Patch()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to start the PowerApps design, start with data or from scratch. In your case, since you already have a SP list with necessary fields, but only mismatched datatype i.e. bool into string - you can do either way. But I would recommend to have boolean field in SP list, you will get a Flip switch (Toggle) in Canvas app based on datatype when you build from data.

[image]

If you are building from scratch or not, still you can manage to identify the Yes/No option ([It can be a single checkbox or two radio buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-list-box-drop-down-list-radio-button#add-radio-buttons)) & store the value in a context variable  using `SET()` function & use that variable when you submit the form.

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables)

Comment: Thank you! Will give it a try

Comment: @o2webdev how did that go?